# Why is the width of the window null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to alert the size of the window and the size of an element in order to put the element where I want it to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var element=$(".element").width();
    var window=$(window).width();
    alert("Element: "+element+" "+"Window: "+window);
  });
</script>
```

When I open it in the browser, I get the width of the element but the width of the window is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use reserved words as variables, `window` is already an object.

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that.

Answer (score 13):

You're shadowing the `window` global variable. Rename your variable:

```
var windowWidth = $( window ).width();
```

Comment: Didn't notice that on the first glimpse. Good catch.